# how to use inline flex property in react native

Tags: react-native

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: desired output]

I want to display inline all these three elements inside each `Block`.
Here's what I have done so far:

```
export default function App() {
const cheers = [
    'cheers',
    'high five'
]
return (
<Block style={{ flex: 1,
                flexDirection: "row",
                alignContent: "space-between",
                marginTop: 50}}
 >
<Block style={{ flex: 2, justifyContent: 'center'}}>
       <Text style={{marginRight: 5}}>Send a</Text>
</Block>
<Block style={[styles.dropdownsRow, {flex: 2}]}>
                            <SelectDropdownMenu
                                data={cheers}
                                onSelect={(selectedItem, index) => {
                                    console.log(selectedItem, index);
                                }}
                                defaultButtonText={'Cheers'}
                                buttonTextAfterSelection={(selectedItem, index) => {
                                    return selectedItem.name;
                                }}
                                rowTextForSelection={(item, index) => {
                                    return item.name;
                                }}
                                buttonStyle={styles.dropdown1BtnStyle}
                                buttonTextStyle={styles.dropdown1BtnTxtStyle}
                                renderDropdownIcon={isOpened => {
                                    return <FontAwesome name={isOpened ? 'chevron-up' : 'chevron-down'} color={'#8898aa'} size={10} />;
                                }}
                                dropdownIconPosition={'right'}
                                dropdownStyle={styles.dropdown1DropdownStyle}
                                rowStyle={styles.dropdown1RowStyle}
                                rowTextStyle={styles.dropdown1RowTxtStyle}
                            />
                        </Block>
<Block style={{flex: 2, justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                            <Text style={{marginLeft: 5, marginRight: 5}}>to</Text>
                        </Block>
<Block style={{ justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                            <Input
                                right placeholder="Type your custom question here."
                                iconContent={<Block />}
                            />
                        </Block>
);
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
dropdownsRow: {justifyContent: 'center', maxWidth: '10%'},
dropdown1BtnStyle: {
    height: 45,
    backgroundColor: '#edeff2',
    borderRadius: 5,
    borderColor: '#444',
},
dropdown1BtnTxtStyle: {color: '#8898aa', textAlign: 'left', fontSize: 14},
dropdown1DropdownStyle: {backgroundColor: '#EFEFEF'},
dropdown1RowStyle: {backgroundColor: '#EFEFEF', borderBottomColor: '#C5C5C5'},
dropdown1RowTxtStyle: {color: '#444', textAlign: 'left'}
});
```

I'm new to react native and don't know how flex property works.
Here's my sample output: [image: sample output]

The whole code found here [whole code](https://snack.expo.dev/@vicrn101/bad42a)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Yoga layout](https://yogalayout.com/) website to find your desired UI and then migrate your styles to your code.